# What is use of suchi (शुची ) , sarva (शर्वा) , pranita (प्रणीता ) , prokshani ( प्रोक्षणी ) , sfaya (सफ्या) wood pieces in yajna?

Tags: yajna, homam

I have heard that any yajna if performing with this five wood pieces. 
suchi (शुची ) , sarva (शर्वा) , pranita (प्रणीता ) , prokshani ( प्रोक्षणी ) , sfaya (सफ्या)

can anyone tell me what is use of this wood pieces.

[image]

Comment: Good Question! I know the use of Suchi, its used for pouring clarified butter Ghee in Yagnas, the first one on the right side is used for Purna Aahuti and/or Sahasradhara, the left most object is kept at the right side of the vedi after the indraya na mama type of mantras the shuchi is touched with that water in the patra.

Answer (score 1):

Prokshani means to sprinkle, so Varuna is invoked into that patra, the rectangular one along with Apa devata with Apa hishteti mantra and two darbha is kept and then the water is sprinkled on the ahutis, kunda etc for suci or purification.

Pranita is the yoni shaped patra, it is for ajyabhag, means, once you offer ahuti of ghee, you have some remaining on the sruk, or the smaller ladle, so you pour the ucchista on water in the pranita to complete the offering.

Comment: Welcome to [Hinduism.se].  Please have a  look at [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/125/5212). Good first post. Can you add how you came to know this information? Is this by your experience in Yagnas? If yes, please [edit] your answer and add that info.

Comment: Could you please provide more details as to which ladle is which ? Are there any online links where the ladles are explained ?